# amsmath - bidi - siunitx possible bug?

Tags: xetex, amsmath, siunitx, bidi

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\usepackage{bidi}

\setmainfont{MinionPro-Regular.otf}      
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\setsansfont{MyriadPro-Regular.otf}
\setmonofont{Monaco}

\newcommand*{\problematic}{\SI{2.8}{\milli\joule\per\square\milli\metre}}

\begin{document}\noindent

\huge\problematic\par

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If either `amsmath` or `bidi` is removed the output is ok.

`amsmath` commented:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Edit: Updated information based on Vafa's answer*

As detailed below, there seems to be something up with `bidi`'s modification of the `\text` command (as it typesets in RTL even if the document text is in LTR). However, there probably should be some active precaution taken for RTL typesetting in `siunitx` as well (even if `\text` did not have this odd behaviour, there would still be an issue inside a 'true' RTL block). I will add the appropriate code to `siunitx` for the next release.

---

The problem here is not with `siunitx` nor (really) with `amsmath` (I think), but is with how `bidi` sets out to modify the `\text` command. You can see the issue with example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
\text{Jk}
\end{document}
```

(The same shows up with `siunitx` as it loads `amstext` for the `\text` command.)

What seems to be happening is that if *only* `amstext` is loaded, `bidi` leaves the `\text` command unmodified, and so standard behaviour is seen. However, `bidi` does check for `amsmath`, and if it is loaded modifies `\text` to have definition

```
\text #1->\@@text {\if@Latin \else \beginR \fi #1\if@Latin \else \endR \fi }
```

where `\@@text` is the original `\text` command. If you trace through, it seems that `\if@Latin` is set incorrectly here. So

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bidi}
\csname @Latintrue\endcsname
\begin{document}
\text{Jk}
\end{document}
```

seems to sort things out.

Answer (score 5):

More of a workaround than a fix but:

[image]

siunitx and bidi seem to be fighting over `\everymath`.

I commented out most of the font usage as I didn't have the fonts and the problem showed up without them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}


\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage[math-style=ISO,bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\usepackage{bidi}

%\setmainfont{MinionPro-Regular.otf}      
%\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
%\setsansfont{MyriadPro-Regular.otf}
%\setmonofont{Monaco}

\newcommand*{\problematic}{\SI{2.8}{\milli\joule\per\square\milli\metre}}

\begin{document}\noindent

\huge\problematic\par

\def\nobidi{\let\beginR\relax\let\endR\relax}

\huge{\nobidi\problematic}\par


\end{document}
```

I feel I must reference

http://xkcd.com/1137/

Comment: what about `amsmath`? it'll work without that as well.

Comment: No you need that to trigger the bidi clash. amsmath, siuintx and bidi all trample on the `\every....` token lists but I ran out of time seeing exactly where the clash is.

Comment: Please see the @Vafa answer.

Answer (score 3):

This supposed to be a comment not an answer but since it is long, I could not submit it as a comment. David Carslie stated that

> `siunitx` and `bidi` seem to be fighting over `\everymath`

`bidi` does not work with `\everymath`.

Joseph Wright said:

> The problem here is not with `siunitx` nor (really) with amsmath (I
>   think), but is with how `bidi` sets out to modify the `\text` command.

`bidi` needs to modify `\text` command the way it does for its RTL puprposes. It is `siunitx` problem which is not ***`bidi`-aware***.

He also said:

> What seems to be happening is that if only amstext is loaded, `bidi`
>   leaves the `\text` command unmodified, and so standard behaviour is
>   seen.

I admit that `bidi` should check for `amstext` not `amsmath` but that does not make any difference here.

He also said:

> However, `bidi` does check for `amsmath`, and if it is loaded modifies
>   `\text` to have definition
>
> ```
> \text #1->\@@text {\if@Latin \else \beginR \fi #1\if@Latin \else \endR
> \fi }
> ```
>
> where `\@@text` is the original `\text` command. If you trace
>   through, it seems that `\if@Latin` is set incorrectly here.

`\if@Latin` is only a conditional that `bidi` package provides so that packages like `polyglossia` set it to false for non-RTL languages and set it to true for RTL languages. `xepersian` makes extensive use of this conditional. On the other hand, as I said above `\text` needs to be modified for RTL purposes so that it typesets text RTL in math mode.

He also said:

> where `\@@text` is the original `\text` command. If you trace through, it
>   seems that `\if@Latin` is set incorrectly here. So
>
> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage{amstext}
> \usepackage{amsmath}
> \usepackage{bidi}
> \csname @Latintrue\endcsname
> \begin{document}
> \text{Jk}
> \end{document}
> ```

You are always making the conditional `\if@LAtin` true which is not the purpose of `bidi` package. For making it more clear, lets look at the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\begin{document}
\[
1+2=3\qquad\text{این یک فرمول است.}
\]
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the text comes out RTL as it should. Let's see how `\if@Latin` works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\begin{document}
\[
1+2=3\qquad\text{این یک فرمول است.}
\]

\begin{latin}
\[
1+2=3\qquad\text{This is an equation.}
\]
\end{latin}
\end{document}
```

So now what is wrong with your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\csname @Latintrue\endcsname
\begin{document}
\[
1+2=3\qquad\text{این یک فرمول است.}
\]

\end{document}
```

The text comes out LTR which is obviously wrong. Hence the problem is not `bidi`; the problem is `siunitx` which is not ***`bidi`-aware***.

**Conclusion:** `siunitx`  needs to always output LTR SI units by using LTR `\text` because even if it uses RTL `\text` in RTL mode, the output would be RTL which is not right.

Comment: @Vafa I'm quite happy to add detect for `bidi` and whatever switch is needed to force LTR mode (if that is correct: I have no idea how unit printing is handled in RTL languages!). However, in my MWE you'll see that there has been no request for RTL typesetting, and so 'normal' text is LTR, but the `\text` content is still coming out RTL, which I think is wrong.

Comment: @Vafa One obvious question for me, as a non-expert, is how exactly the output should be ordered in RTL mode. Do I force the number to be on the left of the unit, or only alter the ordering within the unit, or something else?

Comment: @JosephWright, As a persian speaker I know that unit printing should be always done in LTR mode. The number is always on the left, the unit with LTR ordering on the right side.

Comment: @rowman OK, that makes life relatively easy then. I just need to work out which is the appropriate command and insert it at the start of the internal part of the `\SI` and `\si` commands.

Comment: @Vafa Reading through the docs and code, I find for example `\LRE` and `\@ensure@LTR`, the latter of which seems to be what I want. However, it's only defined for XeTeX. What is the LuaTeX equivalent when `bidi` is loaded?

Comment: Hi, I'm glad to be proved wrong by someone who knows the code here. I was just working backwards from \tracingall ouutput (and between siuntix bidi and amsmath there is quite a lot of tracing:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It was not my intention to prove that you are wrong; Indeed I look at you as one of my masters in TeX. If my answer conveyed that message, then I apologise for being rude.

Comment: @JosephWrigh: The whole thing (numbers and units) regardless of what mode (RTL or LTR) we are in, should be typeset LTR.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi No there is nothing rude about saying that something is wrong.  If you post as many times in public fora as I do, it's a statistical certainty that some of them are wrong. It's much better for the record if it is stated in public which ones are wrong than just sending a private email.

Comment: @JosephWrigh: Unfortunately I removed all the code I had written for LuaTeX; that code is now a part of my commercial TeX system, called Simurgh. `bidi` does not add any code for LuaTeX at the moment so I think you can ignore LuaTeX for the moment.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi Thanks for confirmation on both the LTR part and the LuaTeX side of things. I may have to deal with the more general case (RTL but no `bidi`) at some stage, but for the moment am happy to cover just XeTeX.

Comment: @David Carlisle: Thanks for your kindness but when I think about it now, I regret what I did; I should have sent a private email; I really feel bad.

Comment: @JosephWrigh: Thanks. When I make a change in bidi with respect to LuaTeX, then I will let you know.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi No really. People send me email all the time saying I have said things wrong on xsl-list or xml-dev whatever. I always ask them to repost in public. No need to feel bad, It's good that you showed up:-)