# Equation number enclosing parentheses misplaced with Polyglossia+Hebrew+amsmath

Tags: xetex, equations, amsmath, right-to-left, bidi

I am compiling the following MWE using XeLatex within TeXnicCenter and get a garbled equation number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{Arial}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
2+2=4.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: Not a solution but a comment: I've tried to compile your MWE under LuaLaTeX (MacTeX2013), and apart from a warning message that can be overridden by hitting "r" (for "run"), the MWE seems to compile correctly -- specifically, the equation number is typeset as "(1)".

Comment: Bad interaction with `amsmath`, I'm afraid, although `bidi` and `amsmath` *should* be compatible.

Comment: @Mico Yes, you get a PDF with that procedure, but *tons* of errors. The parentheses come out “correctly” just because all right to left is suppressed because of the errors and of incompatible packages.

Comment: @egreg But I am not including bidi explicitly - does it get loaded by another package or something? And what can you suggest in practical terms to remedy this? Thanks a mil!

Comment: @egreg Could it be somehow a font thing?

Comment: It seems to be the same problem described [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84368/38273), with `bidi` modifying `\text`. Adding `\csname @Latintrue\endcsname` to the preamble fixes the equation numbers. Note that by doing so, `\text{Some text}` will always produce _Some text_ and not _text Some_.

Comment: @Pedro Sorry, this doesn't work for me - still garbled after addding the command you suggested.

Comment: Just to be sure. Did you place the new line after `\setmainlanguage{hebrew}`? That's where it needs to be. Perhaps someone else could confirm; I have tried again from scratch and it is looking fine.

Comment: @Pedro Yes, I did. :(

Comment: @Felix, I reduced the MWE since I see the same with the reduced one (with TeXLive 2012 on Win7)

Comment: @einpoklum Thanks. Now it's almost certain that amsmath is the guilty party.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is caused the label printing macro in `amsmath`.  This uses `\@@italiccorr` to apply an italic correction before the closing brace, and in this hebrew set-up that changes the character ordering.  As the effect of this correction is small anyway, you could remove it in your document.  You also need to change `\maketag@@@` in order that `\eqref` works correctly:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{Arial}

\makeatletter
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\LRE{#1}}}
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip)}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
2+2=4.
\end{equation}

\eqref{eq:1}

\end{document}
```

For comparison the original definition was

```
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
```

Comment: It seems that in the current version `\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\LRE{#1}}}` is not required any more.

Answer (score 8):

@Andrew Swan's answer  breaks `bidi` package's behaviour (see file amsmath-bidi-xetex.def). The right answer is to pass `Script=Hebrew` to your font:

```
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
```

Comment: Hello. I have the same problem of parenthesis, well posed here
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210152/polyglossia-and-equations-numbers?noredirect=1#comment491208_210152 
I verified that the macro of Swann solves my problem but I'm afraid that it " breaks bidi package's behaviour" like @Vafa Khaligi said. Now my analogous command  '\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Traditional Arabic}' doesn't change anything. A solution ?

Comment: I found the solution here
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185987/equation-numbers-are-shown-in-reverse-parentheses

Comment: This doesn't always work