# Issue with arabxetex and equation numbers

Tags: xetex, equations, numbering, arabic, bidi

There seems to be some issue with printing equation numbers when using the arabxetex package.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arabxetex} % 
%\usepackage{bidi} %

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation} 

\end{document}
```

When I compile this I get

E=mc^2            )(1

Whereas if I comment out arabxetex and comment in bidi, it prints correctly.

Any ideas about how to fix this?

(PS: Maybe someone with a higher reputation could add arabxetex to the tags.)

Comment: See 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141231/equation-number-enclosing-parentheses-misplaced-with-polyglossiahebrewamsmath/141437#141437

Comment: @Ronen: The answer you are referring to is very wrong. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

`ArabXeTeX` is not aware of `\if@Latin` boolean of `bidi` package. Fix is easy:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{arabxetex} 
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Arial}
\makeatletter
\@Latintrue
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation} 

\end{document}
```

**Rule of thumb:** `\if@Latin` should be true in LTR-based script and false in RTL-based scripts.