# bidi causes reversed parentheses in equation numbers

Tags: xetex, equations, bidi

When writing a Hebrew document using `xelatex`, `bidi`, and `polyglossia`, equation numbers are in reverse parentheses. How can I fix this?

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, titlepage, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{bidi}

\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a=\frac{dx}{dt}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `[Script=Hebrew]` when you specify your `\hebrewfont`

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, titlepage, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL}

\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a=\frac{dx}{dt}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Notice I have used `polyglossia` to deal with the `bidi` part using `\setmainlanguage` instead of loading `bidi` directly.  Also, `xltxtra` is no longer needed.

This is actually a duplicate of the following question, but unfortunately the accepted answer there is not really the correct solution, so I have added an answer here.

- [Equation number enclosing parentheses misplaced with Polyglossia+Hebrew+amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141231/2693)

Comment: Thanks, where can I find some documentation about how to use my fonts? I tried to use dejavu or DavidCLM but in vain

Comment: Not all versions of the DejaVu fonts contain the Hebrew script. For example, with DejaVu Sans the document works, but not with DejaVu Serif.  Other than the error message that `fontspec` generates, I'm not sure how to check this in advance.

Comment: Just tried it, seems to no longer work

Comment: Does not work any longer for me as well. See https://github.com/bidi-tex/bidi/issues/5