# Equation numbers are shown in reverse parentheses

Tags: xetex, equations, numbering, bidi

I am using

```
\begin{equation} a = b \end{equation}
```

to write the equations in my paper. However, the problem is that the number related to each equation is not shown in the correct format like the picture
[image: wrong numbering format]

How can I fix this?

This is what I have at the first of my code:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}% typeset urls
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{bidi}
\newfontfamily\faFont[Script=Arabic]{Yas} 
\newenvironment{Fa}{\begin{RTL}\faFont}{\end{RTL}}
\newcommand{\fa}[1]{{\faFont\RL{#1}}}
\newcommand\Mark[1]{\textsuperscript#1}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{farsi}
\newfontfamily\farsifont[Script=Arabic]{Yas}
```

Comment: This is unusual. Please show us the full code.

Comment: I'm almost sure that we have here other topic with the same problem.

Comment: Without a minimal example, it's hard to tell, but I suspect a duplicate of [bidi cause reverse parentheses in equations numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178908) (Obviously you may need to choose the appropriate Script for your particular language.)

Comment: @Sigur I searched for it. But I couldnt find the same problem. You may give the link if you think so.

Comment: @HarishKumar I have added part of my code that I think is needed to the quation

Comment: @Pedram This is not a minimal example. Cut out *all* the code that isn't needed and make a complete document compilable that shows the problem.  Also, since you are writing in Persian you might want to use the `xepersian` package instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem is due to an incompatibility between `bidi` and `polyglossia` (as alluded to in V Karen-Pahlav's answer.)  `bidi` expects the boolean `\if@Latin` to be set to true for RTL scripts, but `polyglossia` implements a different way to encode language direction on a language by language basis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{farsi}
\newfontfamily\farsifont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
\csname @Latintrue\endcsname

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
a = b 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been a `polyglossia` bug. `bidi` package provides the `\if@Latin` boolean. This boolean should be true for LTR-based script and false for RTL-based script.