# Reversed numbers with bidi and mathspec

Tags: xetex, bidi

I've recently updated from Debian 'jessie' to Debian 'stretch', and have started having a problem with numbers being formatted backwards when using the `bidi` package in conjunction with the `mathspec` package.  Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
Per 2.7.1 of the RFC.
\end{document}
```

On Debian 'jessie', when built with `xelatex`, this produces "Per 2.7.1 of the RFC."  But on 'stretch' this gives "Per 1.7.2 of the RFC."

Any suggestions of how to fix this?

Comment: If I compile with bidi version 19.1 (TeX Live 2015), the numbers are OK; with version 19.6 (TL 2016) they're reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bidi` package added in version 19.6 (the current one) the following code:

```
\newcount\bidi@digits
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=\@ne
\newXeTeXintercharclass\bidi@digits@charclass
\newXeTeXintercharclass\bidi@dot@charclass
\XeTeXcharclass `\. \bidi@dot@charclass
\bidi@digits=`\0 \loop \XeTeXcharclass \bidi@digits \bidi@digits@charclass \ifnum\bidi@digits<`\9 
\advance\bidi@digits \@ne \repeat
\bidi@digits=`\۰ \loop \XeTeXcharclass \bidi@digits \bidi@digits@charclass \ifnum\bidi@digits<`\۹ 
\advance\bidi@digits \@ne \repeat
\XeTeXinterchartoks \bidi@digits@charclass  \bidi@dot@charclass = {\DigitsDotInterCharToks}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \bidi@dot@charclass  \bidi@digits@charclass = {\DigitsDotInterCharToks}
\newcommand*{\DigitsDotInterCharToks}{\if@Latin\else\char"200F \fi}
```

This has the consequence that when XeTeX finds a digit followed by a period or conversely, it issues U+200F RIGHT-TO-LEFT MARK unless `\if@Latin` is set to true. But it *never* uses either `\@Latintrue` or `\@Latinfalse`, leaving that to the user or to other packages.

The issue is not due specifically to `mathspec`, but appears as soon as you load `fontspec` and is similar in essence to [Equation numbers are shown in reverse parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185987/equation-numbers-are-shown-in-reverse-parentheses)

The solution is the same:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{bidi}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\@Latintrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Per 2.7.1 of the RFC.

\end{document}
```

If you use `polyglossia`, there should be no problem, as the package realizes direction changes in a different way.

[image]

Comment: I did wonder whether it was related to the equation number issue, but was a bit confused by what the solution was.  This works perfectly.  Thanks.