# How to number formulas in Arabic or Persian text

Tags: amsmath, bidi

In an Arabic document I have this code for 2 formulas:

```
\begin{equation}
a=b+c\tag{{alpha}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
d=vt
\end{equation}
```

In the PDF output the parentheses around the formula number ares incorrect:
[image]

How can this be fixed?

Comment: please make a complete test document that would allow this to be debugged, this is with xelatex?

Comment: is this the same as the linked question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185987/equation-numbers-are-shown-in-reverse-parentheses?rq=1

Comment: OP (same name, different account) posted in the answers that https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141231/equation-number-enclosing-parentheses-misplaced-with-polyglossiahebrewamsmath solved the problem.