# bidi and reversed parentheses

Tags: xetex, lists, enumerate, bidi

I have an issue with `xelatex`+`bidi` where parentheses sometimes are reversed on multilingual lines. A minimal example is included:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{bidi}

\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=hebrew]{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew,Scale=1]{Times New Roman}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi})}


\begin{document}

רשימה:
\begin{enumerate}
\item
סעיף שנגמר עם עברית.

\item
$1\neq 2$.

\item
בסעיף העוקב רואים בעיה.
\end{enumerate}

משפט בעברית (עם הערה שנגמרת ב- English).

\end{document}
```

[image: reversed parenthesis]

Note how the 2nd item ending with a math environment 'switched' the context to English, so that the next item has its label parenthesis reversed. The same occurs when a closing parenthesis is preceded by English text.

Questions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178908/46339) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141231/46339) claim that adding `Script=Hebrew` in my `\hebrewfont` should've fixed the issue, but it doesn't. Also, I've seen [an indication](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/185987/46339) that this issue might be related to `polyglossia` and the `\if@Latin` boolean, but I'm not sure how to fix that systemically.

Comment: This seems to be font related. If I run your document with David CLM the enumeration is correct. (My version of Times New Roman doesn't seem to have Hebrew, so I can't test with that.) Also, you need to set the other language to English and then wrap the `English` part in `\textenglish{}` to get the parentheses right in the last sentence.

Comment: This seems to work fine on texlive 2017 on a mac.  Perhaps a bug has been fixed in the meantime.

Comment: @AndrewSwann does it? Using vanilla texlive 2017 (`XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017)`) on Ubuntu Xenial I still get the reversed parenthesis on the following list item after an item concluding in English text (or inline math mode). However, as AlanMunn said, changing font to `David CLM` does take care of that. Also, his remark regarding adding `\setotherlanguage{english}` to the preamble and enclosing English text in `\textenglish{}` solves the problem demonstrated after the list.

Comment: That seems to be further confirmation that it is some font issue.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.