# Polyglossia and equations numbers

Tags: equations, numbering, polyglossia

I'm a little ashamed but I seem as in the first step of Latex... In this example, the  parenthesis of the equation number are inversed. Why? How I can I obtain the good numbering? Thanks.

I give a minimal example. The simple file

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\begin{document}
A sample
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

It's compilation gives[image]

Comment: I'm quite sure this has already appeared. Look also for [tag:bidi] questions

Comment: Yes Thank you. My problem is half solved. I asked the users of this question, and I'll post an answer as soon as I obtain it