# Order of words disturbed by using polyglossia with rtl language?

Tags: xetex, amsmath, polyglossia, hebrew, bidi

When having \setotherlanguage{hebrew} active, then even in an english environment it reverses the order of words in a \text{} and scrambles the labels for equations. 
Here is a minimal working example of this behaviour.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\[\{ x\,|\,\text{yoda says hi\}\]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which gives the output:

[image]

Is there a way to make the words and the label appear in the usual order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's what I think to be a bug in `amstext-xetex-bidi.def` (part of the `bidi` bundle) that does

```
\ProvidesFile{amstext-xetex-bidi.def}[2013/04/04 v0.1 bidi adaptations for amstext package for XeTeX engine]
\def\textdef@#1#2#3{\hbox{{%
                    \everymath{#1}%
                    \let\f@size#2\selectfont
                    \if@Latin\else\beginR\fi#3\if@Latin\else\endR\fi}}}
\endinput
```

but *never* sets `\if@Latin` to true.

I'm not sure where the issue should be dealt with, but a workaround is to add `\@Latintrue` when a left-to-right language is entered.

Example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\{ x\mid\text{one two three} \}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I do, instead,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\makeatletter
\appto{\blockextras@english}{\@ifundefined{if@Latin}{}{\@Latintrue}}
\appto{\inlineextras@english}{\@ifundefined{if@Latin}{}{\@Latintrue}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\{ x\mid\text{one two three} \}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I get the expected output:

[image]

Note that this also fixes the problem with equation numbers; another test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\makeatletter
\appto{\blockextras@english}{\@ifundefined{if@Latin}{}{\@Latintrue}}
\appto{\inlineextras@english}{\@ifundefined{if@Latin}{}{\@Latintrue}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\{ x\mid\text{one two three} \}
\end{equation}
Also the numbers in \texttt{align} are printed right
\begin{align}
 a&=b\\
 0&<1
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

That looks like a bug in `bidi` (egreg thinks) but you can force things back with `\beginL`

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% don't use fontenc with xetex
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
\[\{ x\,|\,\text{\beginL one two three\endL}\}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, I guess this can then be adressed for all cases by something like
\let\oldtext\text  
\renewcommand{\text}[1]{\oldtext{\beginL #1 \endL}}

Comment: yes although might be worth pinging Arthur:-)

Answer (score 3):

This is not `bidi` package bug; it is `polyglossia` package bug. The bug was reported to the author of the `polyglossia` package four years ago with the solution but it has not been fixed to this day.

This question is indeed a duplicate question since it has been asked here before.

`\if@Latin` is only a conditional that `bidi` package provides so that packages like `polyglossia` set it to false for non-RTL languages and set it to true for RTL languages. `xepersian` makes extensive use of this conditional. Consider the following minimal example where `xepersian` package is used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
1+2=3\qquad\text{این یک فرمول است.}
\end{equation}

\begin{latin}
\begin{equation}
1+2=3\qquad\text{This is an equation.}
\end{equation}
\end{latin}
\end{document}
```

As you can see both equation numbers and the parantheses arund them is typeset correctly; the contents of the first `\text` is typeset RTL and the contents of the second `\text` is typeset LTR as one would expect.

**Conclusion:** This is `polyglossia` package bug; it has not been fixed for four years so do not hope that it will be fixed any time soon.

Comment: Please avoid personal rants in answers. Also, if you think this post is a duplicate, then flag it for moderator attention and mention it as such, pointing to the duplicate, rather than providing a duplicate answer (plus rant). Once you've established enough reputation on this site, you can start casting your own vote-to-close - it's a [privilege](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: @Werner: I edited my answer.

Comment: You're wrong: it's `bidi` that changes the definitions of commands, so it's this package that should take care this redefinition is working in the first place.

Comment: @egreg: No, you are wrong because this redefinition works in the first place.

Comment: It's obvious it *doesn't* work in the OP's example.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the question that has been asked before?

Comment: @MoritzFirsching: One possible question is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84293

Comment: @user91727 thanks, I didn't find that when I was looking for it. In any case egregs answer provided a perfect workaround for me

Comment: @MoritzFirsching: That is what the polyglossia needs to do; setting `\@Latintrue` in non-RTL environments (like english, french, etc)

Comment: @user91727 I *never* claimed to know `bidi`. I know a bit of TeX and LaTeX, sufficiently enough to see that the code we are talking about is wrong. How to solve the issue is another matter and requires ***cooperation*** between maintainers. Your proposal of adding `\@Latintrue` is out of the question, I'm afraid: the name is misleading, but it's a secondary question; more importantly, should we count how many writing systems are LTR and RTL?