# How can I correct for a bug in ArabXeTeX that causes problems in left-to-right text?

Tags: xetex, arabic, bidi, bugs

There seems to be a bug in the `arabxetex` package that came with the new MacTeX 2016 distribution. The problem I have noticed is not in Arabic text but rather in ordinary left-to-right text. In particular, numerals involving periods are switched around, so that, for example, `27.6` in the source is printed as

> 6.27

in the outputted PDF. (The problem also seems to affect symbols like §; see below.)

MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xltxtra,fontspec,xunicode}

% Roman
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}

% Arabic
\usepackage[novoc,fdf2alif]{arabxetex}
%\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,WordSpace=2]{USAMA NASKH}
%\usepackage{bidi}

\usepackage[american]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\S 27.6

\end{document}
```

Output should be

> §27.6

but is in fact

> 6.27§

How can I correct for this bug?

Comment: Incidentally, the problem also appears in Arabic text. `\textarab[utf]{أرقام: ١.٢٣}` produces "أرقام: ٢٣.١"

Comment: just to confirm -- did this work correctly with previous editions of tex live?  (if it did, which one(s)?)

Comment: Yes, it has worked for years, most recently with tex live 2015 (but also 2014 and 2013 at least).

Comment: I think this bug is related to `bidi` not to `ArabXeTeX`.

Comment: I also suspect a change in bidi's behavior. The changes I made to the last releases of ArabXeTeX (1.2.0 and 1.2.1) are very unlikely to have caused this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a clarification for your question, the problem is due to `bidi` package which is used from `ArabXeTeX` for  right to left sentences, you can for example enclose dot inside group but this is not an elegant method, best is declare bug to the maintainer of the `bidi` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}
\usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}

\S 27.6  
\qquad  
\S 27{.}6 % this is fine 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, more details (and a workaround) can be found here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312874/polyglossia-or-bidi-bug-d-gets-inverted-to-d

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Certainly `{.}` is not really an option. But the workaround linked by @fc7 works, at least for my MWE. (Not clear to me whether it might have unintended consequences, though.)

Comment: @salim_bou @fc7 Do you know how I can report this bug to the developers of `bidi`? As I posted on [the other relevant page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312874/polyglossia-or-bidi-bug-d-gets-inverted-to-d)  (linked by fc7), the [CTAN page](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bidi/) provides a broken link: <https://github.com/persian-tex/bidi/issues>.