# Period goes before number when a number ends a sentence while using polyglossia hebrew

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, hebrew

I am using XeLaTeX, Windows, `polyglossia`. When I define `\otherlanguage{}` with a right to left language it causes sentences that end in a number to be displayed with the period before the number!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{american}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{document}
This is an example where a number ends a sentence because the number of words in this sentence is 20.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this a known issue? Obviously I could just not end a sentence with a number but that is besides the point.

I look forward to your answer!

Comment: I see the same behavior on my updated TexLive 2016 install with xelatex.  Interestingly, lualatex puts the period in the correct space.  Perhaps you can use that instead?

Comment: hmm, when using Lualatex the Hebrew language doesn't show up, adding the line 
`\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David}`
which I guess is for polyglossia. I guess maybe a different language package that is more compatible with Lualatex might be a solution, should there be one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that this question/answer is an answer also to this question:
[polyglossia or bidi bug: [\d\.] gets inverted to [\.\d]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312874/polyglossia-or-bidi-bug-d-gets-inverted-to-d)