# Number+period positions flipped - only with some TeXLive versions

Tags: numbering, polyglossia, hebrew, right-to-left, bidi

I'm compiling the following document:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{document}

This sentence should have 2 before the point (not after it!): 2.
\end{document}
```

On a GNU/Linux Mint 18.3 at home, the output is in appropriate order, i.e. the 2 appears first, then the period ("2."). On my GNU/Linux Fedora 26 system, the order is reversed, i.e. the period appears first, then the 2 (".2").

Some log lines from the Fedora system:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=xelatex 2017.12.14)  2 FEB 2018 21:50
...
Package: polyglossia 2015/03/25 v1.42.4 Alternative to Babel for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
```

and from the Mint system:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2017.8.23)  2 FEB 2018 21:49
...
Package: polyglossia 2015/08/06 v1.42.0 Alternative to Babel for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
```

What's going on?! Could it be that there's a bug in the *newer* version?

Comment: Sure, why should a newer version not have a new error? In a current texlive 2017 the output is "2."

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Because it's kind of a glaring error, the kind I would think would be "monotonous-disappearing".

Comment: Well the error is gone. So obviously someone saw it and the next version did correct it. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312874/polyglossia-or-bidi-bug-d-gets-inverted-to-d.